# SQL Server - Constraint vs Transaction Scope

Tags: sql-server

I have a business rule to not allow duplicate values on a table column, based on another column value.

```
----- TABLE USER_SECRETS ----

SECRET
USER_ID

----- END --------
```

This means that I cannot have duplicate **SECRETS** when **USER_ID** is empty/null.

I am doing this validation on a stored procedure however I don't want to create a transaction scope on the insert procedure since I want to avoid table locks, which means that it's not 100% safe.

So the ideal scenario would be a constraint. But the constraint (assuming it's possible to create a constraint for this) would not lock the table also?

Thanks

Comment: What version of SQL Server? If 2008+ you can probably use a unique filtered index.

Comment: Yes I am using SQL 2012 Express.